# Python error "No numeric types to aggregate" when trying to use df.resample

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello everyone I am running a code that takes minute data for a month and averages it into hourly.  The code works on some of my files, but not others. I get a very large error and it says "No numeric types to aggregate".  The error is coming from the df = df.resample('1H').mean() line.

**Here is the data I am using.**

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8c77572an2pk8n/OCTTEST.csv?dl=0
```

**Here is the code I am using.**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("octtest.csv", index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True, low_memory=False)
df = df.resample('1H').mean()
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1H"))
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=True, index_label="DateTime")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem `NaN` values are `Null`, what is not default value of parameter `na_values`, so need add it [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#na-values):

```
df = pd.read_csv("octtest.csv", 
                  index_col="DateTime", 
                  parse_dates=True,
                  na_values='Null', 
                  keep_default_na=False)
```